# Missing Block error in simple_form_for tag in js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb, simple-form

I am trying to show a list of comments and a form to make a new comment using AJAX. The simple_form_for block gives the following error: 
ArgumentError in DeliveryNegotiations#show
Showing /home/action/socialpost/app/views/delivery_negotiations/show.js.erb where line #10 raised:
Missing block

This is the show.js.erb file:

```
$("#conversation").html(
    '<% @comments.each do |com| %> \
        <strong> <%=j "User " + com.author_id.to_s + ":" %> </strong> \
        <%=j (com.comment || " ") %> \
        <br/> \
    <% end %> \
  <fieldset> \
    <legend> \
      New comment \
    </legend> \
    <%=j form_for ([@delivery_request, @delivery_negotiation, @comment]) do |builder| %> \
      <%=j builder.text_area :comment %> \
      <%=j builder.hidden_field :author_id, value: current_user.id %> \
      <%=j builder.submit %> \
    <% end %> \
  </fieldset>\
');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please put code into one partial and render it from the js.erb file, As it easy to make the changes.

In _comments_form.html.erb

```
  <% @comments.each do |com| %>
      <strong> <%= "User " + com.author_id.to_s + ":" %> </strong> 
      <%= (com.comment || " ") %>
      <br/>
  <% end %>


  <fieldset> 
    <legend> 
      New comment
    </legend> 
    <%= form_for ([@delivery_request, @delivery_negotiation, @comment]) do |builder| %> 
      <%= builder.text_area :comment %> 
      <%= builder.hidden_field :author_id, value: current_user.id %> 
      <%= builder.submit %>
    <% end %> 
  </fieldset>
```

In your js.erb file

```
$("#conversation").html("<%=escape_javascript(render 'comments_form')%>");
```

I hope this will help you.